# How to view the data in sqlite file running in iphone application?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

How to view the data which is present in the sqlite file in an application running in iphone , like we use mysql work bench to view the contents of the database

Comment: [The Library folder was hidden - this answer helped me][1]
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761695/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-save-the-sqllite-database

Comment: Use command `find /Users/<username>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ -name "*.db" -printf "%T+\t%p\n" | sort` to find the latest modified db file

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you want to view your database when running on Simulator it is located at the following location

```
user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/version of SDK(4.2eg)/Applications/4AF938D6-E981-4971-A588-3424B64E7EE7(eg)/Documents/yourdatabase.sqlite
```

If you want to view the database in your device then you can use a software like `iExplorer`.

Cheers

Edit : The location of sqlite file has changed.

It currently resides in :

```
/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/version of SDK(eg-7.0)/Applications/4AF938D6-E981-4971-A588-3424B64E7EE7(eg)/Library/Application Support/app_name/yourdatabase.sqlite
```

Edit : The location has changed again. It now resides in:

```
/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/789A1317-6C55-4615-A72E-65C824D8C6B9(eg)/data/Containers/Data/Application/0470F5FC-0043-46B7-A21C-A436A56ED714(eg)/Documents/yourdatabase.extension
```

Comment: @Manishh is it changed again as I cannot see CoreSimulator folder in Developer one?

Comment: It changed again, for me it is /System/Volumes/Data/Users/`User`/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*/data/Containers/Data/Application/*/Library/LocalDatabase/

Comment: yourdatabasename.extension (example: basedb.sqlite3) doesn't exist

Comment: For me it was /System/Volumes/Data/Users/User/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/*/data/Containers/Data/Application/*/Library/Application Support/

Answer (score 7):

The Firefox extension **[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817/)** is good and free. Another good, free Mac option is **[SQLite Database Browser](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/SQLite-Database-Browser.shtml)**.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to see data base while app is running in simulator

1. Open finder
2. open `Go` in `toolbar`
3. Then Press and hold command+option you can see  Library option

then process like this

```
Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8FA9F307-45DC-48EC-89ED-E4BDC34CB628/data/Containers/Data/Application/B6105584-49BF-4C0C-BC72-C97FA9B1C194/Documents/database.db
```

Answer (score 3):

Grabbing a database in live mode (meaning an apps-live-database on an iphone) you can use the [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) for downloading the .sqlite file to your computer and explore it with e.g. [MesaSQLite](http://www.desertsandsoftware.com/?realmesa_home)!

Thank you so much for pointing me into the right direction here!

Answer (score 3):

These locations depend on the device you're using in the simulator, so it makes no sense to copy a specific folder as the answer...

**The more general answer about how to figure out the path to the actual database file:**

1. On the dock, right click on Finder, select Go To Folder
2. Paste in the following, and click Go:
   `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`
3. On the top right corner of the Finder window search for the database name you are looking for, then make sure the Search location is set to "Devices" folder, not the whole "This Mac".
4. The db file will show up and if you select it, it will give you the full path! To browse the database content I use this tool: [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org)

Comment: perfect reasoning. thank u man.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable using Xcode plugins, [NCSimulatorPlugin](https://github.com/scinfu/NCSimulatorPlugin) makes it trivial to jump right to your app from Xcode.

[image]

Instead of choosing *Go To Documents* as shown above, choose *Go To Application*.

[image]

Ctrl-click on the app and choose *Show Package Contents*.

[image]

Done!

Comment: N.B plugins are not supported in xcode 8

Comment: True, @matpol. Sadly true.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions involving simulator do work but sometimes you needed to explore the database on a physical device.

If you want to view your sqlite database when running on a device connected to your Mac you'll first need to mount the application files on your mac. You can use iExplorer for that. There is a free demo I used for testing but paid $40 in end:
[iexplorer website](https://macroplant.com/iexplorer)

[image]

Once you mount the apps files you can explore the database using DB browser for sqlite: [DB browser for sqlite website](http://sqlitebrowser.org/). Its not as polished as mysql workbench but its free and gets the job done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The location of sqlite file (Simulator):

```
/Users/myUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/032D9DFB-FBD4-4204-B137-945F1A02FDED(eg)/data/Containers/Data/Application/C10BDAF7-25E2-42CC-A1BE-C5CC04C7567D(eg)**/Library/LocalDatabase**
```

I use the DB Browser for SQLite to view the database: http://sqlitebrowser.org/