# Debugging SQLite db on iPhone

Tags: debugging, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I'm making an iPhone app using Monotouch.
In my app I create an SQLite DB and use it to store a lot of data. 
Is there any way to query the data in the phone/simulator? I mean the data that "lives" inside the app?

It would be nice to see if everything is created in the DB as it should be.

Thx
Nicolaj

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always copy the database file locally and use a tool like Sqlite Explorer to open and view contents:

http://www.singular.gr/sqlite/

An alternative tool:

http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/

One for Mac OS X (Intel):

http://www.desertsandsoftware.com/?realmesa_home

Use [iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) to copy the file over:

[How to view the data in sqlite file running in iphone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644158/how-to-view-the-data-in-sqlite-fle-running-in-iphone-application)

Edit, I've recently switched to [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/).