# Determine Core Data persistence store type of a project

Tags: ios, core-data

I am looking at the code of an iOS application which makes use of Core Data. I want to know the type of persistence store that it currently uses, but could not find any relevant information in Apple's docs.

Where should I look to find this info? Preferably, without having to run the app and `print`ing or entering debug mode.

Comment: Have you tried using iExplorer to see if there is a SQLite db file in the contents of the app? If there isn't you can at least rule out that it isn't using SQLite. Refer to this answer for more; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644158/how-to-view-the-data-in-sqlite-file-running-in-iphone-application/4644189#4644189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the CoreData store type is `NSSQLiteStoreType`. You can search the project for [addPersistentStore(ofType:configurationName:at:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468860-addpersistentstore). That method is used to specify the CoreData type. If they aren't using the default then you'll be able to see what [type](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/store_types) they specify there.